# How to change the text width ( or is it cell width?) in notebook?

Tags: notebooks

I have a whole collection of notebooks here whose text starts on the far left against the screen.
There does seem to be a configuration notebook attached, which I think shows the settings( options) set in the option inspector
For all notebooks the default settings for cell width should be set, but how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! It will be very helpful if you include a screenshot of the notebook. Perhaps you are looking for _Text Alignment_, which can be found under the menu _Format > Text Alignment_.

Comment: Thanks!, see pic.

It are old notebooks from 2006 and text alignment seems to be not working?

Comment: It sounds like you want to learn about *stylesheets.*

Comment: The concept of a stylesheet is not unfamiliar to me.
It is good to know a thing or two about stylesheets in MMA.

Comment: Would be helpful if I could set these notebooks to the correct width somewhere 
Load a kind of configuration file and then the notebooks are set correctly
Attached an example notebook

https://www.dropbox.com/s/byr6rzzd55poa00/Chapter01.nb?dl=0

Comment: It is solved by me.

Comment: There is a corrupted notebook , its from 2006  (mathematica 5.2 ? )

Comment: Corrupt notebook also solved ..easy! and control width text also
Now only some missing packages try to install for the studymaterial
The topic packages is difficul to find ?